# Not deleting the cropped image

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, resize

I use the [one user avatar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-user-avatar/) plugin, In the [one user avatar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-user-avatar/) plugin settings, I ticked the cropping of the uploaded image and entered the desired size

[image]

When the user uploads his avatar, Cuts and saves the original size according to the size selected in the settings, Then it clears the original size of the image, When the user uploads a new avatar, the new cropped image replaces the old cropped image, The function below does the work of cropping and saving the image :

```
public static function wpua_action_process_option_update( $user_id ) {
        global  $blog_id,
                $post,
                $wpdb,
                $wp_user_avatar,
                $wpua_force_file_uploader,
                $wpua_resize_crop,
                $wpua_resize_h,
                $wpua_resize_upload,
                $wpua_resize_w,
                $wpua_admin;

        // Check if user has publish_posts capability
        if ( $wp_user_avatar->wpua_is_author_or_above() && ! $wpua_force_file_uploader ) {
            $wpua_id = isset( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) ? absint( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) : 0;

            // Remove old attachment postmeta
            delete_metadata( 'post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true );

            // Create new attachment postmeta
            add_post_meta( $wpua_id, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id );

            // Update usermeta
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', $wpua_id );
        } else {
            // Remove attachment info if avatar is blank
            if ( isset( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) && empty( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) ) {
                // Delete other uploads by user
                $q = array(
                    'author'         => $user_id,
                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                    'meta_query'     => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar',
                            'value'   => "",
                            'compare' => '!='
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $avatars_wp_query = new WP_Query( $q );

                while( $avatars_wp_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $avatars_wp_query->the_post();

                    wp_delete_attachment( $post->ID );
                }

                wp_reset_query();

                // Remove attachment postmeta
                delete_metadata( 'post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true );

                // Remove usermeta
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', '' );
            }

            // Create attachment from upload
            if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit'] && ! empty( $_FILES['wpua-file'] ) ) {
                $file = $_FILES['wpua-file'];
                $name = isset( $file['name'] ) ? sanitize_file_name( $file['name'] ) : '';
                $type = isset( $file['type'] ) ? sanitize_mime_type( $file['type'] ) : '';
                $file = wp_handle_upload( $file, array(
                    'test_form' => false,
                ) );

                if ( isset( $file['url'] ) ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $type ) && preg_match( '/(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i' , $type ) ) {
                        // Resize uploaded image
                        if ( 1 == (bool) $wpua_resize_upload ) {
                            // Original image
                            $uploaded_image = wp_get_image_editor( $file['file'] );

                            // Check for errors
                            if ( ! is_wp_error( $uploaded_image ) ) {
                                // Resize image
                                $uploaded_image->resize( $wpua_resize_w, $wpua_resize_h, $wpua_resize_crop );

                                // Save image
                                $uploaded_image->save( $file['file'] );
                            }
                        }

                        // Break out file info
                        $name_parts = pathinfo( $name );
                        $name       = trim( substr( $name, 0, -( 1 + strlen( $name_parts['extension'] ) ) ) );
                        $url        = $file['url'];
                        $file       = $file['file'];
                        $title      = $name;

                        // Use image exif/iptc data for title if possible
                        if ( $image_meta = @wp_read_image_metadata( $file ) ) {
                            if ( trim( $image_meta['title'] ) && ! is_numeric( sanitize_title( $image_meta['title'] ) ) ) {
                                $title = $image_meta['title'];
                            }
                        }

                        // Construct the attachment array
                        $attachment = array(
                            'guid'           => $url,
                            'post_mime_type' => $type,
                            'post_title'     => $title,
                            'post_content'   => '',
                        );

                        // This should never be set as it would then overwrite an existing attachment
                        if ( isset( $attachment['ID'] ) ) {
                            unset( $attachment['ID'] );
                        }

                        // Save the attachment metadata
                        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );

                        if ( ! is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                            // Delete other uploads by user
                            $q = array(
                                'author'         => $user_id,
                                'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                                'meta_query'     => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key'     => '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar',
                                        'value'   => '',
                                        'compare' => '!=',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            );

                            $avatars_wp_query = new WP_Query( $q );

                            while ( $avatars_wp_query->have_posts() ){
                                $avatars_wp_query->the_post();

                                wp_delete_attachment($post->ID);
                            }

                            wp_reset_query();

                            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file ) );

                            // Remove old attachment postmeta
                            delete_metadata( 'post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true );

                            // Create new attachment postmeta
                            update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id );

                            // Update usermeta
                            update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', $attachment_id );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I want the original image to be preserved as well, That's why I changed this part of the code And I also kept the original size :

```
$uploaded_image->save( $file['file'] ); # old code
$uploaded_image->save( $uploaded_image->generate_filename() ); # new code
```

But there is a problem, When a user uploads a new avatar, The old original image will be deleted and the new original image will replace it, A new cropped image is also created, **But the old cropped image is not deleted**, What changes should I make in the code to remove the old cropped image?

I did a lot of searching on the net and checked a lot of codes, but I didn't get any results.

**I appreciate any reply from you.**